# How to step through some Common Lisp code, inspecting the return value of forms?

Tags: debugging, emacs, common-lisp

Maybe this is noob-ish but I'm losing my mind after this. I discovered with very much surprise that CL's stepper doesn't show the return value of the various forms. What I mean is that the debugger can inspect the frames and the REPL allows to manually inspect the variables, but for instance in a code like

```lisp
(defun fact (n)
  (if (<= n 0)
      1
      (* n (fact (- n 1)))))

(fact 5)
```

I cannot instruct the debugger to say "hey, I just stepped over form `(<= n 0)`, which returned `nil`, then I stepped on `(- n 1)`, which returned value `4`". This can be done in Emacs-lisp and in Clojure (I use Emacs, but it's not the interface I'm interested in). I know there exist the form `(step)`, but it is implementation-dependent and for what I could see on both SBCL and CMU it doesn't do what I mean. So my question is, **can CL's debugger do this (stepping + printing value just evaluated)?** If yes, is it just one implementation? Can you provide a MWE?

Thanks!

Comment: Try using `(trace fact)`

Comment: Common Lisp is a language with many implementations and IDEs. "Debugger" is also a very general term, with a lot of different tools for it. For a better question you would tell us a) what exactly you are using and b) what you have tried.

Comment: Barmar, as I specified in the question, I already tried it. @Rainer, I use Emacs, and I have tried both SLIME and Sly, and both SBCL and CMU Lisp.

Comment: Also you can add the statement (break) to a point you want the execution to break into debugger. From that point on you can continue with (step) at the frame REPL through the tools you're using (either the direct REPL to your impl, or through slime/sly etc.).

Comment: @AlbusMPiroglu that's true, but in usual CL code I don't bind names to temporary results, so to inspect the "inner" data flow I have to either evaluate subexpressions (potentially slow and having side-effects), or change the code to have bindings. No big deal actually, since it's the usual workflow when working in C/C++, I just thought CL had more sophisticated ways to do data debug (whereas from the little I understood it shines with stack traces and inspections)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common Lisp is a language specification, not an implementation.  As such, expressions like 'CL's stepper' or 'CL's debugger' are category errors: languages do not have steppers or debuggers, implementations do.  The language specification provides an interface, [`step`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_step.htm), by which such a thing might be invoked, but says

> `step` implements a debugging paradigm wherein the programmer is allowed to step through the evaluation of a form. The specific nature of the interaction, including which I/O streams are used and whether the stepping has lexical or dynamic scope, is implementation-defined.

Thus the answer to your question is that no, 'CL's debugger' can't do this because 'CL's debugger' does not exist.

*Implementations* of the language may provide more-or-less support for this.  I know, for instance, that [LispWorks](http://www.lispworks.com/) does, for instance.  I don't know whether other implementations do.  CL as a language is also reflective enough that a portable stepper could probably be written: [sly-stepper](https://github.com/joaotavora/sly-stepper) might be such a thing but I am not sure.

---

Here is an example of LW's non-IDE stepper in use:

```
CL-USER 7 > (step (let ((x 0)) (/ (sin x) x)))
(let ((x 0)) (/ (sin x) x)) -> :su

Error: Division-by-zero caused by / of (0.0 0.0).
  1 (continue) Return a value to use.
  2 Supply new arguments to use.
  3 (abort) Return to debug level 1.
  4 Return to stepper level 1.
  5 Quit from stepper.
  6 Return to debug level 0.
  7 Restart top-level loop.

Type :b for backtrace or :c <option number> to proceed.
Type :bug-form "<subject>" for a bug report template or :? for other options.

CL-USER 9 : 2 > :a
(let ((x 0)) (/ (sin x) x)) -> :sr 0.0
0.0 
0.0

CL-USER 8 > (step (let ((x 0)) (/ (sin x) x)))
(let ((x 0)) (/ (sin x) x)) -> :s 2
   0
   0 
   (/ (sin x) x)
      (sin x) -> :si
      0.0 
      x -> :sr 1
      1 
   0.0 
0.0 
0.0
```

In the first interaction I let it run until it got the error, aborted from that back into the stepper, and then told the stepper to return zero.  In the second I stepped through until it was about to evaluate `x` and then told it the result of that was `1` causing it to return zero.

The non-IDE stepper above is documented [here](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw80/lw/lw-common-lisp-50.htm#LWUGRM)step) & the IDE stepper is [here](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw80/ide-m/ide-stepper.htm#IDE)ide-stepper%20chapter).

Comment: I am aware this is implementation-dependent, that's what I was referring to near the end of my question. What I meant is, **does such a debugger exist?** I thought LispWorks was an _editor_, but now I discover it's also a separate _implementation_? Also, sly-stepper is close to what I was asking, but it still displays the value _after_ execution of the entire function, not during.

Comment: If you are aware that it is implementation-dependent, then you should avoid meaningless terms like 'CL's stepper'.  I have added an example of LW's stepper in use, but I'm going to mark this question as unanswerable: I regret answering it now.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought the metonymy was obvious. Anyway, I really appreciate your edit and the links you added at the end, now I have a clearer picture.

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky. I just tried it with abcl (armed bear common lisp, an implementation running on jvm), and it's not stepping in.

With sbcl, you need to declare debug optimization to start stepping in your function:

```
(defun fact (n) 
  (declare (optimize (debug 3) (speed 0)))
  (if (<= n 0)
      1
      (* n (fact (- n 1)))))
```

Then, to see the returned value of a frame you can use trace in addition to step, as Barmar pointed out. Mind that the fact recursive function return-values show after you recurse all values and forms start returning.

Lispworks debugger is quite good as it shows all the info you wanted and more. For example it can macroexpand at will during debugging. I just tried checking allegro express edition (acl, allegro common lisp is another implementation), and its debugger is even more detailed, and I am having difficulty understanding how to use it so far. I should start reading up their quite good documentation.

What I wonder is, since you seem to be asking an implementation-independent way of getting frame results from the debugger, whether it is really the debugger that you should be aiming? If, for example you want to write some library for debugging some code, such as your own implementation independent graphical debugger, then using a debugger may not be what you need. You would need to use and manipulate the s-expressions directly and evaluate them yourself, effectively writing your own debugger (You can also check cl-mcclim's debugger interface). But the effort would be much more easier than doing it with another language, given that you have lisp's reader / parser etc. And that makes me wonder if Paul Grahams's OnLisp book, Continuations chapter would be a good place to point for further ideas. Or maybe I am a bit confused about this. This stackoverflow's Q/A style doesn't let me make this a further discussion topic, does it? Oh well.

Another point you raised is data debugging. Common Lisp defines a symbolic computation machine, and thus abstracts over any memory access and addresses. Although you can get a unique id for any object using print-unreadable-object function, as it is defined in the standard. And some implementations will return the memory location, but it is probably of little use for a memory analysis.

I am writing this post because I think I share the frustration. Probably because of similar reasons I've been trying to develop a visualiser library. The need to simplify the development process is profound, and I don't like the fact that my development speed is faster at work using a mainstream language compared to at home using Common Lisp. Even though I express a design more fluently and faster with lisp, the tooling at work around the language, the IDE, the debuggers and data analysis make the development cycle go faster.

By the way, what is MWE??

Comment: Your answer hands me various points to investigate, and as a whole I think I underestimate the problem. What I would (ideally) like is a stepper like Edebug/CIDER in Emacs. I originally thought those weren't manipulating the code, but simple wrappers around CLI debuggers. Turns out, IIUC, this not the case, and for CL _this particular_ feature of debugging (stepping through s-expr) is implementation-dependent, and rn the only implementations known to provide this are LispWorks and Allegro. The MWE is actually the code in the original question, as the interface I imagine would start from _that_